# Rewriting array, repeating objects in array

Tags: java, arrays, oop

The point is i know how to rewrite an array. but what should i do if i have two repeated objects in it.
for example
We have an array of students
`St[] {new St (id: 1,name: a), new St (id: 1, name: a), new St (id: 2,name: b),}`
And the first two *St* are reapeted. I need to rewrite that code without reapiting

I tried this piece of code, to figure out which obj are reapeted

```
 Person[] objects = Main.fillStudentsArray();

 for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
                if( i != j) {
                    if (objects[i].name.equals(objects[j].name)) {
                        System.out.println(objects[i] + "\n" + objects[i].hashCode());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("this is different objects");
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
```

Nevertheless the information looks like that

```
1 0
0 1
```

two the same objects, which looks like

```
1 a - *same hashCode
1 a - *same hashCode
```

How can I rewrite it into a new array without reapiting?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I’ve no idea what you were really trying to ask, but… Make a `Set` to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many scenarios, utilizing a Set is commonly considered when aiming to hold a collection of unique objects. However, the options available vary based on your specific objectives. From my perspective, these two approaches are among the most straightforward.

##### 1. Use HashSet and override the hashCode() and equals().

```
public class Student {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Student(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Student student = (Student) o;

        if (id != student.id) return false;
        return Objects.equals(name, student.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student1 = new Student(1, "Elon");
        Student student2 = new Student(1, "Elon");
        Student student3 = new Student(2, "Elon");

        Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
        students.add(student1);
        students.add(student2);
        students.add(student3);

        System.out.println(students.size()); // 2
        System.out.println(students); // This will print student1 and student3 (because student2 is a duplicate)
    }
}
```

```
//Here you can see how to populate the set with the array.

Student[] studentsArray = {
       new Student(1, "Elon"),
       new Student(1, "Elon"),
       new Student(2, "Elon")
};

Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(studentsArray));

System.out.println(students.size()); // 2
System.out.println(students); // This will print student1 and student3 (because student2 is a duplicate)
```

##### 2. Use stream with distinct() and override equals().

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] studentsArray = {
                new Student(1, "Elon"),
                new Student(1, "Elon"),
                new Student(2, "Elon")
        };

        Student[] distinctStudents = Arrays
                .stream(studentsArray)
                .distinct() //uses equals()
                .toArray(Student[]::new);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(distinctStudents));
    }
}
```